# Cronjob is returning EOF error while looking for matching ``'

Tags: python, linux, macos, cron

I am running a cronjob script which for some reason stopped working. I may have missed a typo or something in my cronjob file.

I keep getting an EOF error while looking for matching ``'

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is my cron job.

```
* * * * * /bin/bash `python /Users/reid/Documents/Programs/sortphotos/src/sortphotos.py --keep-duplicates --sort \%Y/\%m-\%B --rename %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S --day-begins 4 /Users/reid/Dropbox/Camera\ Uploads/ /Users/reid/Dropbox/Camera\ Uploads/`
```

I know my actual python command runs and executes when I run it. I figured it could be the lack of knowing where python is but this was working before.

What could be the issue with the EOF?

Comment: i'd try dropping `/bin/bash` and the ``

Comment: Why did you put that horrible grave accent in front of `python....` ???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
* * * * * python /Users/reid/Documents/Programs/sortphotos/src/sortphotos.py --keep-duplicates --sort \%Y/\%m-\%B --rename %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S --day-begins 4 /Users/reid/Dropbox/Camera\ Uploads/ /Users/reid/Dropbox/Camera\ Uploads/
```

1. drop /bin/bash
2. drop the back quotes

Comment: I realized that my % parameters within the command need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. If I leave my cron job command written as is, the issue is where I am adding the parameter to rename the file. The attributes I am using to configure the names,

```
--rename %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
```

need to be escaped, so:

```
--rename \%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S
```

Thanks for your help.